# Install adb in ubuntu 10.0.4

Tags: ubuntu, path, adb

I am trying to configurate adb to be used with ubuntu 10.0.4. I installed all th sdk,  then i puted the path of pmatform-tools and tools in PATH. but when i try to run `adb command unkown`.
I tried `cd path/sdk/plateform-tools` then `adb devices` .
  I have all the time unkown command but, when i tried, `./adb devices` every thing is all right. what is the problem and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you added the adb to PATH. One way to permanently add it to PATH is to edit $HOME/.bashrc:

```
export PATH=$PATH:path_to_android_sdk/tools:path_to_android_sdk/platform-tools
```

After this, close and open the terminal and the sdk should be in PATH. 
You can see what adb is used by executing this command in the terminal:

```
which adb
```

After this, go to the file and grant execution rights to it:

```
chmod a+x adb
```

Answer (score 0):

After you add in PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:path_to_android_sdk/tools:path_to_android_sdk/platform-tools
```

try use :

```
source ~/.bashrc
```